# What is 18坪? (じゅうはち + つぼ = ?)

Tags: readings, counters, numbers, dakuten

What is 18坪? (じゅうはち + つぼ = ?)

I found this sentence

１８坪の店内【てんない】は落【お】ち着【つ】いた雰囲気【ふんいき】で、壁面【へきめん】にはぐるりとＳＰ、ＬＰレコードなどが１万枚【いちまんまい】並【なら】ぶ

https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/culture/music/20220701-OYT1T50230

I did not know how to pronounce １８坪, but I found this explanation:

One or two 坪【つぼ】 are read using 和語【わご】, three can be 和語【わご】 or 漢語【かんご】, and the rest are (you guessed it) 漢語【かんご】

https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/japanese-counters-list/

So how does one combine じゅうはち + つぼ? I thought I'd just ask rather than guess incorrectly, since sometimes the final 8changes in the number's pronunciation, like in 800【はっぴゃく】 and 18歳 【じゅうはっさい】.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

坪 is a traditional Japanese unit of room size which corresponds to 3.31 m<sup>2</sup>. So 18坪 is about 59.5 m<sup>2</sup>.

The kanji itself is always pronounced as つぼ without rendaku.

> One or two tsubo are read using wago, three plots can be wago or kango, and the rest are (you guessed it) kango.

This means *tsubo* is counted like so:

- 1坪: **ひとつぼ**
- 2坪: **ふたつぼ**
- 3坪: **みつぼ or さんつぼ**
- 4坪: よんつぼ
- 5坪: ごつぼ
- 6坪: ろくつぼ
- 7坪: ななつぼ or しちつぼ
- 8坪: はちつぼ or はっつぼ
- 9坪: きゅうつぼ
- 10坪: じゅっつぼ or じっつぼ
- 18坪: じゅうはちつぼ or じゅうはっつぼ
- and so on

The first three are indeed very tricky, but the rest should be straightforward. (摘み also shows this tricky pattern. ひとつまみ, ふたつまみ, さんつまみ, よんつまみ, ...)